# Reducing the space between sections of the UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there a way to reduce the space between two sections of a UITableView? There are about 15 pixels between every single section I have. I did already try to return 0 for `-tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and `-tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` but that doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was using a **grouped** tableView and setting the header/footer height to `0.0`. But it was showing a gray area with a (default) 30point height. Using `0.0` is unaccepted. you must use any value above `0.0` e.g. `0.0001`.

Comment: As @Honey says `0.0` does not work. I have a more thorough answer for the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22185534/2789144

Answer (score 269, accepted):

It was a bit tricky, but try this code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
           heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 6.0;
    }

    return 1.0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
           heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5.0;
}

- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
           viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
           viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Change the values accordingly. To remove the space, I think 0.0 will not be accepted. The smallest sane value seems to be 1.0.

Comment: You should return 5.0f instead of 5.0, because of double - float conflicts

Comment: You can even return 0.00001f as a height and you'll get a height of 0 pixels/points.

Comment: As @Klass points out, you cannot use `0` as the height – you will get the default height.

Comment: I've heard that fractions introduce some blurring around the text, so it might be safer to go with a whole integers as Tomen suggests.

Comment: you must NOT use values like "0.00001", it will break rendering of bottom views. all your texts will be blurred badly. use only integer values

Comment: Why not use CGFLOAT_MIN? It's made for these kind of scenarios :)

Comment: @AndreiFilip: Have you tried it out? Does it work? Clearly the value 0 is made for the kind of scenario where you want a height of 0, and _that_ doesn't work.

Comment: I can confirm that CGFLOAT_MIN does indeed work. Make sure you also return a basic UIView as the header and/or footer views.

Comment: If using swift, you can return `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

Answer (score 142):

For all who want to shrink the distance to 0 you have to use:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;
```

Because the serving of the UITableViewDelegate does only make an effect starting from floats greater than zero.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.0;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
}
```

(using iOS 4.1 with XCode 4.0.2)

Comment: return 0.0001; is working for me. I am using xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1

Comment: I only need to return CGFLOAT_MIN in the first two methods and it works fine.

Comment: instead of 0 use `return .leastNormalMagnitude`

Answer (score 33):

You can actually set the footer/header/cell heights in Interface Builder under the size tab. By default the header/footer are set at 10.0.

Comment: I think such behavior was added in iOS 5.0 or iOS 6.0, but yes - it's now much easier to setup distance between groups.

Comment: I know this is old but I wanted to comment that as of XCode 5 and iOS 7, it seems like this HAS to be done in code. I set it in interface builder to 0 and it still was set to 1 until I set it in code to 0.

Comment: With Xcode 6 and iOS 8 it seems to be working with just the config in the storyboard.

Comment: they're set to 18 on xcode 7 by default. but that's by far the easiest solution!

Answer (score 29):

You have to reduce the section header/footer height. Then the space between sections will be reduce.

try this code

It works for me :-)

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 2.0;
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 2.0;
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also reduce the height of section footer and header from the storyboard. In the tableview -> size inspector. Go to Section Height.

[image: Size inspector for UITableView in storyboard.]

By  default it is set to 22 for Plain style table and 10 for grouped style table. You can configure values by increasing / decreasing the values for header and footer separately.

Answer (score 7):

Use this perhaps, 0 will not work as expected

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return .leastNormalMagnitude
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was because I was using a grouped table view style (`UITableViewStyleGrouped`). When I changed it to a plain style (`UITableViewStylePlain`) my `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method was the only thing determining the size of each section header.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE FOR iOS7:** Due to ARC autorelease update, here's @Martin Stolz code edited.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return 6;
    return 1.0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

(Using iOS7, Xcode v5.0)

Answer (score 0):

For me just this issue got resolved just by using the following code,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return section == 0 ? 1 : 20 // 20 is my other sections height
}
```

Returning **1** for the first section has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change header/footer space the following methods **have to** be implemented:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

AND

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

(use corresponding methods to change footer height)

The following code completely removes spaces around sections:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5, iOS 13+

### Option 1 - When creating the table view

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

### Option 2 - More flexible for other views and sections

```
// Top space for sections
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

// Bottom space for sections
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```