# Label that displays 'Prototype Cells' in Storyboard displays in simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a Table View (not `UITableViewController`) with dynamic prototype cells.
However, when you drag a single cell into the `tableView`, a label with the word 'Prototype Cells' is displayed but then, this label (without the word 'Prototype Cells') appears when I run the app in the simulator.

Does anyone know why that is?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: check if this link helps : http://www.colejoplin.com/2012/09/28/ios-tutorial-basics-of-table-views-and-prototype-cells-in-storyboards/

Comment: @staticVoidMan Sorry that tutorial didn't seem to help, I really feel like I'm missing something small. I have deleted the cell and started again to see did I miss any connections but everything seems to be working fine. Thank you for your edit also, you can probably tell that I'm a newbie to this

Comment: np, try to see what was the issue and post an answer or delete the question (_if the solution was too basic like missing IB connections_)

Comment: Can you clarify. Are you seeing your cells as expected __and__ the "label" thing? Or just the "label" thing? From your description, it sounds like an empty section header.

Comment: @TimothyMoose My cells are appearing perfectly, it is just between the Navigation bar and the first cell there is an extra small section that is blank. It is the section that displays 'Prototype Cells' in storyboards. Hope this clears it up

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't, I need a reputation of 10 to post an image. If you place a 'uitableviewcell' in a 'uitableview' in storyboards you will see the small section that I refer to

Answer (score 1):

The "Prototype Cells" label in the storyboard resembles a section header view, so you may be inadvertently generating an empty one. This could happen if you've implemented any of the related `UITableViewDelegate` methods. For example, the following would do it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}
```

But without seeing a screenshot or your view controller's code, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380989/2944521).

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0);
```

Thank you to everyone for your help.