# Search Controller in navigation item show black bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

Hi I have setup search controller using

```
private func setupSearchbar() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Contacts"

        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

    }
```

Everything was working fine until I add this code

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_BOLD, size: 22) ,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes   = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_BOLD, size: 34) ,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

Now When I tap on search bar big bottom black bar appears

How to fix this ?

View Debugging

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the UITableView header space. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380966/how-to-remove-header-and-footer-space-from-a-uitableview

Comment: @BryanP Nope This is not, Until I have added UINavigationBar code this was working.

Comment: black color is backGround color of your viewController view default color. Set your viewcontroller view color. And also check your tableview's constraints also.

Comment: @PratikSodha View by default color is white, You mean UIWindow color, and yes I have setup all constraints correctly, (top,left,bottom,right with 0 constant without margin)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Try remove constraints for tableview and give it again.

Comment: @PratikSodha I have already tried this, check view debugging image in edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay So I am able to fix this issue. I am sharing this so this might helpful to other facing the same issue.

to fix this issue. In view will appear method I have set  `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `true`

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    }
```

Hope it helps to someone :)

Here is output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true

UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's I don't want to do. I want this properties.