# reducing space between cells in UITableView - why won't this code do this?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

any ideas why I can't reduce/remove the space between cells in a Grouped UITableView (one cell per section).  I'm including the following in the controller:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

I'm still getting spaces between cells even with this code.  Put a border around the cells and the space isn't from the cells themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reducing the space between sections of the UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview)

Comment: In particular, the magic solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview/2817696#2817696)

Comment: thanks - re "magic solution" link - this worked - do you know why one needs to explicitly allocate header/footer view like in "viewForHeaderInSection" to enable things to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PengOne's suggestion to look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview/2817696#2817696), what I didn't have in place that made it work was the following:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] autorelease];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] autorelease];
}
```