# Indexed UITableView without section header

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

I'd like to implement a grouped and indexed UITableView without section headers.

I'm using `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` to return my titles.

I also implemented `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and returned `nil` as well as `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and returned `0.0f`.

Both doesn't remove the section headers. There is still a space between the different sections.

Comment: So you want the table to look as if you had only one section?

Comment: Basically that's what I want, yes.

Comment: See my answer here. It should solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview/2817696#2817696 Set the values to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not find a solution. In the end, I had to subclass `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`) and use a `UITableView` with transparent background and the style set to `UITableViewStylePlain`. Then, I created custom cells for the first and the last row (with rounded corners) and some transparent margin left and right. I can give you more details if you want, but as it does not answer your question straight, I'll just share [this link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for now.