# Expand and collapse static table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, static, datasource

I have a static table view in my application. This table view is used for preferences.
A section in the table view only has one cell which holds a `UISwitch`. When this switch is activated, I want to show the section beneath and when it is not, I want to hide the section beneath. All the sections (also the one which should be hidden / shown) is set up using Interface Builder.

Is there any way to hide or show this section when the table view is static as a static table view doesn't have a data source? Should it be easier, I could also agree to use the same section but add / hide rows from this section when the switch is on or off.

**EDIT**

I have come closer how to do this.

Setting the height of the cells in the section and the height of the footer and header of the section to 0, I can *nearly* hide the section. I still have some spacing between the section above and the section below that I cannot figure out how to get rid of.
Does anyone have an idea where this extra spacing comes from? See the photo below.

This is the code I use to *nearly* hide the section.

```
/* Will display cell */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2)
        cell.hidden = YES;
    else
        cell.hidden = NO;
}

/* Height of cell */
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2)
        return 0;

    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

/* Height of section header */
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 2)
        return 0;

    return [super tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
}

/* Height of section footer */
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 2)
        return 0;

    return [super tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section];
}
```

This is how the table view looks now. There is still some space I need to hide. The extra space is between the sections labeled "Arbejde" and "Anden".

[image: Extra space]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the code in the question. Just set the height to `1.0f` instead of `0`. It seems that the height only has an effect when it's value is greater than zero.

[Reducing the space between sections of the UITableView.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389157/486845)

Comment: Hi, you didn't answer your own question. You added how you solved another issue. My question is the same as yours - how did you manage to get the switch expanding the cells? I am having a lot of difficulty and your answer is the first to actually do anything however I cannot get it to work with a switch, it won't expand. Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue I am having is that I am not using sections. The second issue is how do you communicate with the second method that sets the height? I can communicate with the first method fine but the second isn't functioning for me.

Answer (score 1):

For static cells, I just use this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  let cell = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
  if cell.isHidden {
    return 0
  } else {
    return cell.bounds.size.height
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial this may helps you [www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

Comment: The tutorial uses a data source for the table view. My table view is static and therefore it does not use a data source but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**For static cells** I found no decent answers either. If you wish to drop sections or expand a cell then this is the code I used.

Create a BOOL Value in your .m

```
@interface yourClassName (){


BOOL ddMenuButtonPressed;

}

@end
```

ddMenu means `drop down menu`.

Next I set the bool value to false in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
ddMenuButtonPressed = false;
```

I then initialise the ddButton (in storyboard control+drag from your button or switch to your .h file and create action and set name to ddMenuButton) and use this method in my .m file.

```
- (IBAction)ddMenuShow:(UIButton *)sender
{
     if (sender.tag == 0) {    
        sender.tag = 1;
        ddMenuButtonPressed = true;

    } else {
        sender.tag = 0;
        ddMenuButtonPressed = false;

    }
    //very important that you include these
    //they update the view like a viewDidLoad statement without leaving the screen
    //if you have any data entry points in your cell like a textfield it **will not** erase that data fortunately
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Finally we add the following method:

```
// Handle expanding and minimising cell or section

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //if the section is 0 (and there is only one cell) and ddMenuButtonPressed hasn't been pressed
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && ddMenuButtonPressed == false){

    //return the height you have it set as in story board (or a number)
    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
    //if the section is 0 and the ddMenuButton has been pressed
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && ddMenuButtonPressed == true){
    //change the cell height to 380 or whatever size you want
    return 380;
    }
    //otherwise leave cells as they are
    else {

    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
}
```

And that's it. No fancy coding, nice and clean (minus the commenting) and simple and you can use this over and over for as many sections as you like.