# What is the space between UITableView Sections?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3, space

What is the default space that is in between UITableView sections?

Here's an example.
 [image]

Thanks for all the help!

Shredder2794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812438/591586) indicates it's a combination of header and footer height, both of which are 10 by default. So 20 total.