# Hide footer view in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, footer

I have been working to **hide the footerview** for while. My problem is I have a button in footer when I click the button one section will be added below as the last section and the button too will shift to the newly created section and now I want to hide the footer in the previous section of the table after the update of sections.

```
footerView.hidden = YES
```

I used this in the button action but its not working.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are four solutions. They are,

**Solution 1:**

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return 1.0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return 1.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can set the footer/header height via interface builder under the size tab.

**Solution 3:**

set **contentInset** property.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0);
```

It is used to make the top and bottom touch the edge.

**Solution 4:**

implement the below, set the values as per your condition. 0.0 will not be accepted. The lower value should be 1.0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    if(section == 0) {
       return 6;
    } else {
       return 1.0;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return 5.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: @@Ramshad You should reference or attribute the work you copy off. Also, specifying 0.00001f results in zero height. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview

Answer (score 18):

This should do it

```
tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = YES;
```

**In Swift 5:**

```
 tableView.tableFooterView = nil
```

Comment: I don't think you're trying to hide the "footerView" then, but rather the last cell of the section. My answer correctly shows how to hide the footerView

Comment: Its not hiding the footerview man . Next section pulls after the footerview .

Comment: There are two kinds of footer views: tableFooterView and sectionFooterView. Hence the confusion...

Comment: To make it work you should do this, `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    [tableView.tableFooterView setHidden:YES];
    
    return 1.0f;
}`   **Key point is return 1.0f**

Comment: This does not work. Section footers are not hidden and are not even reduced to 0 height.

Answer (score 9):

This can do it
by implementing delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Referring to @J.Hong answer, **Swift4** version (iOS 11.3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Comparing to @Tim Newton answer:

- there is no need to call `titleForFooterInSection`
- simplify `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` -> `.leastNonzeroMagnitude` (more Swifty IMO)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0** solution that also removes the pesky 1px border between the previous cell and the following header.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I have to show/hide the footer based on a HTTP request. How I can apply changes? Because your example is executed initially, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

in swift4:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

When not using custom views, return `nil` from `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` and `0` from `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *footerTitle;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldHideFooter;
```

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.shouldHideFooter ? nil : self.footerTitle;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.shouldHideFooter ? 0 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 solution:** (hides section footers, you may need another piece to get rid of the table footer)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}
```

Comment: This one helped me. Thank you.