# Space Between Sections in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, layout

I need to reduce the space between two sections of`UITableView`.  I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview) but the solution doesn't allow for my custom header view because it combines the space of the footer and header.

Here is a picture of the `UITableView`.  The black color is the `UITableView` background color.

[image: tableview screenshot]

Comment: I'm confuse about what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove the black space between the end of one section and the header of the next section?

Comment: Yes I want to remove the black space

Comment: Xcode 6.0 and higher needs only `self.tableV.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
        self.tableV.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;`

Comment: have you got what you wanted? Bcz I am not having any success

Comment: Had a similar issue today and this saved my life >
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296414/992461

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Did you try override this function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Comment: Yes it doesn't work I think the minimum value for that function is one

Comment: I add another method as well try to override both, I didn't try but it should work

Comment: When I add that code it defaults to the standard footer size

Comment: I notice you cannot return 0 in heightForFooterInSection, try to return  0.00001f instead as a height and you'll get a height of 0 pixels/points.

Comment: For Swift 3 you can return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude.  Thanks Icaro!

Comment: This will only work if you also override the viewForFooterInSection method. You may return nil in this method (at least in iOS14. I haven't tried in previous versions).

Comment: for iOS 13 at least, this only works with @Mig70 comment

Answer (score 243):

On iOS 15 you may want to reduce the sectionHeaderTopPadding

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks This worked for me in iOS 15.0... But this code disable the deafult funcitonality for latest section to be shown.It works as normal tableview with rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats awful how apple introduced non-zero padding as default. epic

Comment: Any way to apply to all table views within the app without having to set for each one?

Comment: yay! finally, something worked! but what about earlier versions? :(

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala, earlier versions didn't have the sectionHeaderTopPadding, so no worries.

Answer (score 44):

I think you can solve this by adjusting the footer view height to its min: in Storyboard or XIB.[image]

I don't know what you have written in your code for footer height. Sorry if I am wrong.

Possible duplicate of [Hide footer view in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445301/hide-footerview-in-iphone-tableview)

Comment: When I try that the minimum footer size is 1 which still leaves a 1point gap

Comment: Either you can change the color of that footer to the header section color.. So that the 1px black color can be ignored.

Comment: @SudhinDavis you are right that there is footer height in xib but if we want no footer then Icaro's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30386480/2849443 is correct

Comment: That answer is far better than mine. Since that will also remove the extra lines from empty cells. Thanks.

Comment: I liked possible solutions given in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445301/hide-footerview-in-iphone-tableview

Comment: If a height of 1 for the footer is still too large you can return 0.01 in `heightForFooterInSection` in code.

Answer (score 31):

For Swift 4+ you need to implement these two methods

```
extension MyViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }

}
```

Comment: Those are UITableViewDelegate methods. You do not override them.

Comment: Ok I edited it my answer to a better and general implementation. Cheers.

Comment: Nice! Not sure why this has not more upvotes. It's important to return a `UIView` or `nil` in `viewForFooterInSection`. Just using `heightForFooterInSection` (like mentioned in other answers does not work)

Answer (score 13):

For Swift 3

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Comment: That is a UITableViewDelegate method. You do not override it.

Comment: @DrewC You do override it in Table View Controller.

Answer (score 10):

**For Swift 5+:**

There is some space for the headers and footers by default. That's why I was having the problem of setting an exact separation for the sections.

My solution to having a separation between 2 sections is the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 24
    } else if section == 1 {
        return 32
    } else {
        return 40
    }
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    nil
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    nil
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

As you see for viewForFooterInSection and viewForHeaderInSection I needed to return nil.

In case you only want to change the footerHeight, just return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude for heightForHeaderInSection, and return the heights for each section in heightForFooterInSection.

Comment: Adding viewForFooterInSection table view delegate function alongside heightForFooterInSection fixed the spacing for me

Answer (score 7):

Along with the [answer posted by Icaro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386480/2064585) I would like to add that you also need to implement the `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` method returning `nil` for the section you want to remove the empty space below
It will then become:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.001f;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the method `heightForHeaderInSection` for defining the space between header & cell text. You can also change it depending on different sections for eg. at some sections you may need to show more distance & under some, you don't want to show gap. For such case you can use `CGFLOAT_MIN` which is 0.000001f. Giving you an example, how you can use different section with different header heights:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0 || section == 2)
    {
        return 55.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  heightForHeaderInSection defines the height of the headerView for the section, not the space between them, which is what the OP was asking about.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

I just simply had to reduce the top padding for the tableview section header:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

TableView Delegate methods doesn't effect with float value is 0.0f. Try giving a value greater than that.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.00001f;
}

- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` methods and defining the sectionFooterHeight via `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`, one can alternatively just

```
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

and the spacing between sections while no footer is present will go away.

The mechanism is that by default this value is set to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

As long as

- it stays `UITableView.automaticDimension`
- there are no delegate/dataSource methods that implement the configuration of footer i.e. `titleForFooterInSection`/`viewForFooterInSection`
- table view's style is set to `.grouped`

then UITableView will deliberately insert a spacing between sections with no view.

You change `sectionFooterHeight` to 0, the magic goes away.

Comment: helpful, in my case, the TableView is Grouped. thx~

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 13.2, you can adjust the height of the header and footer of sections in the storyboard - see screenshot below:

[image: Height of Header and Footer of Sections in Xcode 13.2]

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken you want to remove the gap between your sections and the last cell from the last section. If this is the case you should check a couple of things but it is mainly because of the footer. And if it is because of the footer you should try to both return nil for viewForFotterInSection and return 0 for heightForFooterInSection.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

And if your case is not because of the footer you can check out these:

1. insetForSectionAt function -> return zero for this function

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
   }
   ```
2. Check for the table view style and play with it. Try to set it as "grouped".

   ```
   UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
   ```
3. Check your cell view layout
4. Try to set the style to grouped and set the footer view to nil and its height to zero

Answer (score 2):

This also may help :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the `tableView` in your storyboard/objectCode and ensure that the style is set to `Plain`, instead of `Grouped`. You can find this setting in the attributes "Inspector" tab.

```
let myTableView : UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.register(TableCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 123/255, green: 190/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()
```

Comment: please chek and verify in your code that **Style is set to plain** if story board you can find this word in tableView (Attribute inspector)

Answer (score 1):

Work for me

```
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 10
// ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by implement the delegate `heightForHeaderInSection` & `heightForFooterInSection`.

The return vaule should not be 0, even if the SectionHeader or the height of SectionFooter  is 0, it need a very small value, try `CGFLOAT_MIN`.

for my example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (section == [self.dataArray indexOfObject:self.bannerList]) {
    return 46;
}
return CGFLOAT_MIN;
```

}

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 5 iOS 15

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 16.0 // spacing between Sections
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work iOS 15 and greater

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

It will reduce automatic space between header and cell, if you have multiple header sections.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need spacing only for the first cell** at the top of your UITableView and your header sections after scrolling must have no space, **instead** of using `contentInsets.top` do this:

Add fake **`UIView`** with your spacing by adjusting it's `height` and place it into **`UITableView.tableHeaderView`**

Here's how it should look like (using SnapKit):

```
let spaceView = UIView()
spaceView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.height.equalTo(10)
}
    
tableView?.tableHeaderView = spaceView
```

`tableHeaderView` is not fixed, so in this case, spacing at the top of `tableView` will be `10`, but after scrolling `tableView` spacing from top will be gone, **spacing only stays at the top**.