# Remove vertical space between sections in a Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been searching for this one for quite a while and didn't find a solution that works for me.

I've setup the `UITableView` as `Grouped` and each section header will hold a `UIView` that will be used to represent a **question** on a question-answer application and each section will hold a number of rows that will be used to represent the **answers** to that previous question.

The problem is: there is a vertical spacing between each section group, and I want to remove it.

[image: Captions on red to explain]

I already tried to do like suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview) but looks like it didn't worked.

I also tried using a minimal value for the `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection` as `0.00001` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364067/space-between-sections-in-uitableview). But I'm getting the following error:

`'section footer height must not be negative - provided height for section 1 is -0.000010'`

Is there a way to make this work without abandoning the strategy (section for question, rows for answers)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview. Use this function.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a grouped tableview instead of a plain one? A plain one shouldn't have that spacing in there by default.

Comment: Yes @tww0003, I cannot allow the section header to remain fixed on top while scrolling in the section content. I just tested changing it to `Plain` and it worked, but then there's that problem that I just mentioned.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For some reason `tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0.0` was not working but `tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0` did, even with the `UITableView.style = .grouped`.

Also I was using an empty `UIView` as my footer view.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: is it possible to remove a space between cells at a particular index ?