# UITableView section footer not hiding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, tablefooterview

I have created a `UITableView` using the `Interface Builder` I have a section footer space there, I have designed my custom view as the section footer. But I want the section footer to be hidden initially and only load it after a service call.

I have tried

```
self.tableview.tablefooterview.hidden = YES
self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0f
```

I have also set the height in delegate methods, but the table footer view is not hiding at all. How do I hide the table footer view.

Answer (score 1):

check this Link for how to [Hide footer view in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445301/hide-footer-view-in-uitableview)

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` delegate method :-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set section footer value to more than 0(zero). I tried to set it as 0.000001 and it works.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 0.000001;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableview.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
    self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;
    self.tableview.tableHeaderView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableview.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
    self.tableview.tableFooterView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableview.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```