# How do I hide Xamarin.Forms TableView header/footer with a custom renderer on iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am wanting to create a page layout where I display multiple `TableView`s along with other views such as a `Label` in between each.

In doing this I need the ability to:

1. Make the `TableView` not default to a vertically expanded layout option (the default which does not seem changeable) so that they can be stacked in a `StackLayout` vertically.
2. Hide the corresponding `UITableView` section header/footers so that there isn't excess vertical spacing between.

I have achieved this with the following `CustomTableView` control:

```
public class CustomTableView : TableView
{
    public bool NoHeader { get; set; }
    public bool NoFooter { get; set; }

    protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        if(!VerticalOptions.Expands)
        {
            // Call OnSizeRequest that is overwritten in custom renderer
            var baseOnSizeRequest = GetVisualElementOnSizeRequest();
            return baseOnSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        }

        return base.OnSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    public Func<double, double, SizeRequest> GetVisualElementOnSizeRequest()
    {
        var handle = typeof(VisualElement).GetMethod(
            "OnSizeRequest",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(double), typeof(double) },
            null)?.MethodHandle;

        var pointer = handle.Value.GetFunctionPointer();
        return (Func<double, double, SizeRequest>)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(Func<double, double, SizeRequest>), this, pointer);
    }
}
```

and the custom iOS renderer for this which follows the advise from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445571/1090359) for hiding `UITableView` headers/footers:

```
public class CustomTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    public override SizeRequest GetDesiredSize(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Control.LayoutIfNeeded();
        var size = new Size(Control.ContentSize.Width, Control.ContentSize.Height);
        return new SizeRequest(size);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.NewElement is CustomTableView view)
        {
            Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
            SetSource();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        var view = (CustomTableView)Element;
        if(e.PropertyName == TableView.HasUnevenRowsProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetSource();
        }
    }

    private void SetSource()
    {
        var view = (CustomTableView)Element;
        if(view.NoFooter || view.NoHeader)
        {
            Control.Source = new CustomTableViewModelRenderer(view);
        }
        else
        {
            Control.Source = Element.HasUnevenRows ? new UnEvenTableViewModelRenderer(Element) :
                new TableViewModelRenderer(Element);
        }
    }

    public class CustomTableViewModelRenderer : UnEvenTableViewModelRenderer
    {
        private readonly CustomTableView _view;

        public CustomTableViewModelRenderer(CustomTableView model)
            : base(model)
        {
            _view = model;
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if(_view.HasUnevenRows)
            {
                return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
            }

            return base.GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath);
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            if(_view.NoHeader)
            {
                return 0.00001f;
            }

            return base.GetHeightForHeader(tableView, section);
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            if(_view.NoHeader)
            {
                return new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }

            return base.GetViewForHeader(tableView, section);
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            if(_view.NoFooter)
            {
                return 0.00001f;
            }

            return 10f;
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            if(_view.NoFooter)
            {
                return new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }

            return base.GetViewForFooter(tableView, section);
        }
    }
}
```

I then create a simple `Xamarin.Forms` `ContentPage` to implement this as such:

```
public class TablePage : ContentPage
{
    public TablePage()
    {
        Table1 = new PageTableView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Cyan,
            Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection("Table 1")
                {
                    new LabelEntryTableCell("Label A"),
                    new LabelEntryTableCell("Label B")
                }
            }
        };

        var label1 = new Label
        {
            Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
                "Vivamus accumsan lacus orci. Nulla in enim erat.",
            Margin = new Thickness(15, 5, 15, 0),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
        };

        Table2 = new PageTableView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection("Table 2")
                {
                    new LabelEntryTableCell("Label C"),
                    new LabelEntryTableCell("Label D")
                }
            }
        };

        var label2 = new Label
        {
            Text = "Duis vulputate mattis elit. " +
                "Donec vulputate lorem vitae elit posuere, quis consequat ligula imperdiet.",
            Margin = new Thickness(15, 5, 15, 0),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green
        };

        StackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { Table1, label1, Table2, label2 },
            Spacing = 0
        };

        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        Title = "Custom Table View";
        Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = StackLayout
        };
    }

    public PageTableView Table1 { get; set; }
    public PageTableView Table2 { get; set; }
    public StackLayout StackLayout { get; set; }
}

public class PageTableView : CustomTableView
{
    public PageTableView()
    {
        Intent = TableIntent.Settings;
        HasUnevenRows = true;
        RowHeight = -1;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        NoFooter = true;
    }
}

public class LabelEntryTableCell : ViewCell
{
    public LabelEntryTableCell(string labelText)
    {
        var label = new Label { Text = labelText };
        var entry = new Entry();

        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { label, entry },
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Padding = 10
        };
    }
}
```

---

This all seems to work as expected, however, when the `TablePage` first displays much of the `CustomTableView` content is chopped off. I can then rotate the device to landscape and the problem corrects itself, showing my layout as I intend. Then rotating then device back to portrait still shows the correct layout with no more information from the `CustomTableView` being chopped off anymore in that orientation either. This happens consistently every time. See a demo of this here:

[image: Rotating fixes the problem]

I can also fix the problem by adding this to the `TablePage`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // This will also fix the problem, but you see a flash of the old layout
    // when the page first displays.

    StackLayout.RedrawLayout();
}

...

public class CustomStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public void RedrawLayout()
    {
        InvalidateLayout();
    }
}
```

---

How do I correct this problem? My custom control/renderer/page works as intended whenever I do the rotation/OnAppearing hack to correct it and I am not sure why. It seems like I need to call some re-draw method on the `UITableView`.

**Sample Project**

If you want to see the full source/project for this isolated test scenario you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kspearrin/TableViewTest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew this issue in iOS. When the tableView first loaded, we can't get the correct contentSize even if we have written `LayoutIfNeeded()`. But after the page is appearing then we refresh it, we can get the correct contentSize. This is why

> This will also fix the problem, but you see a flash of the old layout

**Solution1:** My suggestion is we can try to refresh the tableView in a bit milliseconds delay when the tableView will dispaly:

In the TablePage, I subscribe a MessagingCenter to refresh the layout

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Refresh", (sender) =>
{
    StackLayout.RedrawLayout();
});
```

Then I send the message in the renderer:

```
//I define this bool field to make sure this message only be sent at the first time after tableView loaded
private bool shouldRefresh = true;

public override async void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    if (tableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 == indexPath.Row)
    {
        if (shouldRefresh)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Refresh");
            shouldRefresh = false;
        }  
    }
}
```

**Solutin2:** We can also try to define an estimated rowHeight to give a contentSize when the tableView first loaded:

```
public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return 100;
}
```

But in this solution the height must be predefined and calculated by ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on overriding `WillDisplay`. I was able to create a solution based off of this idea, though without using `MessagingCenter`. I just passed a reference of the wrapping `CustomStackLayout` to the `CustomTableView` and call `RedrawLayout` from `WillDisplay` in the renderer. Works, but seems kind of a hacky still. I would prefer to be able to calculate the proper height somehow initially if possible. I will accept your answer if no other good solutions come in.

Comment: @kspearrin yeap, I know it’s the best if we can find a way to calculate the height at initial time.

Comment: @kspearrin Excuse me, have you found a better way to solve this problem?