# Remove spacing between table sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

The 2 rows on top (Monthly, Annual) are a different section than the 3rd row at the bottom (Lifetime). I want to remove the space that is above the Lifetime row in between the sections. I tried changing the header height to 1.0 in the heightForHeaderInSection method but it didn't seem to work.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat headerHeight = 0.0;

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            headerHeight = [self featuredProductHeaderView].frame.size.height;
            break;
        case 1: {
            if (_groupOneSectionTitle) {
                headerHeight = 1.0;
            }
        }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQoQj.png]

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the footer height as well, and make sure you are not returning a title for header/footer nor are you returning a view for header/footer.