# How to reduce space between section header?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I would like to eliminate the space in these two places programatically?

[image]

I have tried this without much luck:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 35.50;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

UPDATE:
I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview) and it doesn't help me.

After applying the suggested solution of

```
self.yourTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
self.yourTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

I get this, but thats not correct. The whole section title is gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your cell have margin
Open Debug>Debug view hierarchy and see where is your margin

Answer (score 0):

Why you return 35.5 in the `heightForHeaderInSection`? It is your header height?

Try this and remove `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` functions from your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
self.yourTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
self.yourTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

Or this

-

```
 (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please see updated question. zero deletes the entire title as well.

Comment: I checked updated answer, and I think the problem is in your `UITableViewCell` It have some vertical spacing constraints with extra padding. Or maybe that constraints related to margins, not borders of cell. Please re-check your cell autolayout constraints

Answer (score 0):

I give you clear reference from below link

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817308/reducing-the-space-between-sections-of-the-uitableview)

Credit goes to Tomen

Comment: I have seen this. It doesnt help me. Please see updated question.